# How to access a Layout item in a parent from child?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following parent xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_places_linearLayout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        style="@style/GenericProgressBackground" >

        <ProgressBar style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.ListView
        android:id="@+id/bottomactionbar"
        style="@style/BottomActionBar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The com.example.ListView is my custom component that contains an AsyncTask. When this task is completed, I wanted to set the parent's ProgressBar visibility to GONE.

So, when AsyncTask in child component is done, I try the following:

```
LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout)getParent();

((LinearLayout)llParent.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Unfortunately the line llParent.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel) is null... any chances I can overcome this issue?

Thanks,
Felipe

Comment: what is null? llParent or the result of calling findViewById()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me a generalization of what you want is a listener or delegate method that your custom ListView can call when the ListView's AsyncTask reaches `onPostExecute`. That would make your custom component reusable (e.g., what if you use it on another view with a `ProgressBar` that has a different id?)

I would create an inner interface (`com.example.ListView.AsyncTaskCompletionListener` or some such) with a single method (`onAsyncTaskComplete` for example), give the `com.example.ListView` an instance variable of that type, and have the Activity implement the interface and the method.

In `onPostExecute` of your custom ListView's AsyncTask, check to see that the listener instance variable is not null, and then call the interface method on it.

When you set up the ListView in the Activity, set the ListView's listener instance variable to the instance of the Activity (`myListView.setAsyncTaskCompletionListener(this);`) and inside the listener method, you can set the ProgressBar visibility to GONE.

ListView snippets:

```
package com.example;
public class ListView extends android.widget.ListView {
    private AsyncTaskCompletionListener listener;
    public AsyncTaskCompletionListener getAsyncTaskCompletionListener() {
        return listener;
    }
    public void setAsyncTaskCompletionListener(AsyncTaskCompletionListener atcl) {
        listener = atcl;
    }
    ...
    public interface AsyncTaskCompletionListener {
        public void onAsyncTaskComplete();
    }
    private MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        ...
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onAsyncTaskComplete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your Activity snippet:

```
public MyActivity extends android.app.Activity implements com.example.ListView.AsyncTaskCompletionListener {
    com.example.ListView customListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Could be onResume or somewhere else
        ...
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_horizontal);
        customListView = (com.example.ListView)findViewById(R.id.bottomactionbar);
        customListView.setAsyncTaskCompletionListener(this);
    }
    ...
    public void onAsyncTaskComplete() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion works great and I find it to be a very clean approach to my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sounds like what you really want is a `ListFragment`. Regardless of which way you pick, just provide a setter for the ProgressBar in your ListView and pass it in the `onCreate()`. Then you can directly access the `ProgressBar` in your ListView cleanly (always check for a null, though).

Comment: Using Android 2.2, no ListFragment allowed.
I am not sure I understood what you suggested.
Thanks

Comment: Just like the accepted answer, but instead of providing a listener (which is also a good approach), you provide a setter for the list's "progressbar": `customListView.setProgressBar(theProgressBar);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try just giving your progress bar its own id, and access it directly without trying to go through its parent. Also, the inner LinearLayout "loadingPanel" is unnecessary.  Just pop your progress bar to the outer list.  Here's a snippet of an XML layout including a progress bar from the SDK samples:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:secondaryProgress="75" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/progressbar_1_default_progress" />
...
```

Also also, try naming your resource ID using only lower-case letters, numbers, and '_'.

Comment: Not sure how I could directly access the progress bar.
The whole point of this thread was how to access an parent item from the child.
Thanks